# Htacces redirect php for case sensitive

Tags: php, .htaccess

Hello i have following url and redirect to another url by using .htaccess file.
Following examples of urls:

```
http://www.ussafety.com/Apco to http://72.3.171.36/s/Apco
http://www.ussafety.com/APco to http://72.3.171.36/s/Apco
http://www.ussafety.com/APPo to http://72.3.171.36/s/Apco
http://www.ussafety.com/ApcO to http://72.3.171.36/s/Apco
```

So i have one url with different change of letter of apco word. So can it possible to redirect by entering changing leeter of word with only one line code in htacces?

Comment: so what have you tried....?

Comment: if i understand well you are looking for case **in**sensitive redirect ?

Comment: yes case insesitive

Comment: I tried this RewriteRule ^Apco$ "http\:\/\/72\.3\.171\.36\/s\/Apco" [R=301,L]
But accroding to this i must add 4-5 line different case of letter. And i have lots of url like this.

Comment: see https://perishablepress.com/case-insensitive-redirectmatch/#i

Comment: @CROZET thanks it working now in all cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} http://www.ussafety.com/apco [NC]
 RewriteRule .* http://72.3.171.36/s/Apco [R=301,L] 
</IfModule>
```

Use the `[NC]` flag after writing the redirect condition.That tells Apache to ignore casing for the pattern match. Just write all character in lowercase in condition statement....